Isoperimetric Property/Theorem for regular/uniform 3D shapes
What I call the "Isoperimetric Property for n-sided Polygons" is that for each $n \geq 3$, the regular $n$-gon has the minimum perimeter of all $n$-gons with a given area and the maximum area of all $n$-gons with a given perimeter, and that a circle is the optimal shape since it's the limiting shape as $n$ approaches $\infty$.
I know this is true for cubes as well with rectangular prisms, but is it true for all uniform $n$-gonal prisms?  I'm assuming so but am not sure.  I'm also assuming that the more sides a Platonic Solid has, the closer its surface area and volume come to the optimal surface area and volume of its circumsphere.  Is this correct too?
Finally, is there a specific term better than "isoperimetric property in 3D", like "iso-surface area"?

There are only 5 Platonic solids in 3D so it don't make sense to talk about the limit of Platonic solids with more and more faces. But I think than among all solids with the same volume, the sphere has the least surface area.

I will focus on polygonal prisms. You know that an $n$-gon's ratio $p^2/A$ (where $p$ is perimeter, $A$ is area) is minimized when the $n$-gon is regular. In that case (using an irrelevant circumradius $r$),
$$\frac{p^2}{A}=\frac{(2nr\sin\frac\pi n)^2}{(nr^2\sin\frac\pi n\cos\frac\pi n)}=4\pi\frac{\tan\frac\pi n}{\frac\pi n}>4\pi.$$
Now, the prism of height $h$ has volume and surface area
$$V=Ah,$$
$$S=2A+ph=2A+\frac{pV}A.$$
If $V$ is fixed, then we can vary the polygon's $A$ and $p$ independently (and $h$ is determined by $A$). If $A$ is also fixed, it's clear that $S$ is minimized when $p$ is minimized. Therefore, in 3D as well as 2D we should take the polygon to be regular:
$$p=\sqrt{4An\tan\tfrac\pi n}$$
$$S=2A+\frac{\sqrt{4n\tan\frac\pi n}\,V}{\sqrt A}$$
Differentiate $S$ with respect to $A$ to find the minimum:
$$2-\frac{\sqrt{4n\tan\frac\pi n}\,V}{2\sqrt A^3}=0$$
$$A=\sqrt[3]{\tfrac14n\tan\tfrac\pi n\,V^2}$$
$$S=\sqrt[3]{2n\tan\tfrac\pi n\,V^2}+\frac{\sqrt{4n\tan\frac\pi n}\,V}{\sqrt[6]{\tfrac14n\tan\frac\pi n\,V^2}}$$
$$S=3\,\sqrt[3]{2n\tan\tfrac\pi n\,V^2}$$
$$\frac{S^3}{V^2}=54\pi\frac{\tan\frac\pi n}{\frac\pi n}>54\pi$$
(Note that the ratio $S^3/V^2$ for a sphere is $36\pi$. For a cylinder the minimum is $54\pi$, occurring when the cylinder's height equals the circle's diameter.)
What is the shape of this optimal $n$-gon prism? It's not uniform; the height is different from the polygon's edge length $e$:
$$h=\frac VA=\sqrt[3]\frac{4V}{n\tan\frac\pi n}$$
$$e=2r\sin\tfrac\pi n=2\sin\tfrac\pi n\,\sqrt\frac{A}{n\sin\frac\pi n\cos\frac\pi n}=2\,\sqrt[6]{\big(\tfrac1n\tan\tfrac\pi n\big)^3A^3}=\sqrt[3]{\tfrac4n\big(\tan\tfrac\pi n\big)^2\,V}$$
$$\frac eh=\tan\tfrac\pi n$$
